# Printing a game board using a Data.Map

Tags: haskell

I have a `Data.Map (Int, Int) [String]` representing the board of a game (I assume that at a position on the map there can be more than one piece). Let's say that i have the following Map:

```
fromList [ ( (0,1) , ["piece1", "piece2"] )
         , ( (2,2) , ["piece3", "piece4"] ) ]
```

What I am trying to do is printing the table, in this case a 3 X 3 table, with the elements of the map at the position specified while the rest of the spaces are empty or have an 'x'. I have tried to use foldl and map and combinations of the 2 but I just don't get it how i should do it. I have to mention that i am very new to Haskell. Any help would be great!

Output should be:

```
x | piece1piece2 | x
x | x | x
x | x | piece3piece4
```

Comment: it is actually a String, when i add a piece to the board, i add it as a string.

Comment: that helps thanks! I'd still like to see example output, though, otherwise it's impossible to know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: " x  |  piece1piece2|  x  \n\
\ x  |  x  |  x   \n\
\  x |  x  |  piece3piece4  "

Comment: Edit that into the question please, especially as a code block so it's easy to see the spacing you want.

Comment: it should look like a matrix, that's why i have \n\ in my output, but i don't know how to put a newline here :(

Comment: type it as you want to see it, select the whole text, and press Ctrl+K (or click the "code block" button in the WYSIWYG editor)

Comment: i figured it out. thanks

Comment: I edited -- does that look right?

Comment: yes it looks ok

Comment: the output is a String, I think i should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that will get you started.  It works by iterating over the (row,column) coords of the board.  In the iteration it looks up the string to print for that location, defaulting to "x" on failure.   Finally the board is printed one row at a time.

The final format is not exactly what you had in mind but it should get you most of the way there.

```
import Data.Map as DM
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List.Split


main = do
  let pieces = fromList [ ( (0,1) , ["piece1", "piece2"] )
                        , ( (2,2) , ["piece3", "piece4"] ) ]

      -- prepare piece name lists for printing
      p2 = fmap concat pieces  

      height = 3
      width = 3

      -- iterate over board in row/column order
      -- lookup name - use "x" if not found
      namesInOrder = [fromMaybe "x" $ DM.lookup (row,col) p2
                         | row <- [0..height-1]
                         , col <- [0..width-1]
                     ]


      -- split into chunks of one row each
      rows = chunksOf width namesInOrder

  -- print each row on its own line
  mapM print rows
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try and understand and modify if i need to. It is a very good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start off with the import of `Data.Map.Strict`. Generally the way to do it is

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
```

You have a `Map (Int, Int) String`, and you need to print out a square array of strings. It seems that the first thing you need to do is calculate the dimensions of the array. We can do that with an indexed fold. It looks like a good one for the job is

```
foldlWithKey' :: (a -> k -> b -> a) -> a -> Map k b -> a
```

Hrmm... Those type variables aren't very informative. Let me relabel them:

```
foldlWithKey'
  :: (acc -> key -> elem -> acc)
  -> acc
  -> Map key elem
  -> acc
```

This function takes an initial value of an accumulator, and a function indicating how to modify that accumulator for each key and element in the map. Let's make a type representing the dimensions of the board:

```
data Dim = Dim { rows :: !Int, cols :: !Int }
```

Now we can write

```
getDim :: Map (Int, Int) a -> Dim
getDim = M.foldlWithKey' update (Dim 0 0)
  where
    update (Dim rs cs) (r, c) _
      = Dim (max rs (r + 1)) (max cs (c + 1))
```

For each entry in the `Map`, we adjust the row and column counts as necessary.

Now that we know the dimensions of the board, let's build a representation of it that will be more suitable for printing. The simplest way to do this is probably to iterate over the row and column numbers, looking up the pairs in the map. Let's start by writing a function to get a single row:

```
getRow :: Int -> Dim -> Map (Int, Int) a -> [Maybe a]
getRow r (Dim {cols = cs}) m =
  [ M.lookup (r, c) | c <- [0 .. cs - 1] ]
```

Here `Nothing` means that the key was not in the map, and `Just whatever` means it was.

Now we can use that to get all the rows:

```
getRows :: Dim -> Map (Int, Int) a -> [[Maybe a]]
getRows dim@(Dim {rows = rs}) m =
  [ getRow r dim m | r <- [0 .. rs - 1] ]
```

Now we can think about displaying! I'm going to leave this to you, but I suggest you consider using `Data.List.intercalate` and `map` to turn each row into a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going to try it out